# Сохранение изменеённых данных после закрытия

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, jupyter-notebook

Анализирую данные на Jupyter Notebook v.5.7.8, импортирую данные из CSV файла в DataFrame с помощью функции `pd.read_csv`. После этого, несколькими функциями удаляю пустые, лишние и ошибочные данные. Потом сохраняю и закрываю Jupyter.

Как сделать, чтобы DataFrame, который хранит обработанные данные, сохранялся внутри файла .ipynb после закрытия Jupyter?

Это необходимо для того, чтобы не импортировать данные каждый раз в DataFrame, а уже работать с ними при новом открытии.

Comment: Вам в любом случае придется сохранять измененные данные куда-то. Либо в другой csv-файл, либо через pickle, либо через HDF5 - то есть, все равно в файл. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098654/how-to-store-a-dataframe-using-pandas

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Я надеялся на чудо :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать очень простой трюк - сохранять обработанные данные в новый файл и проверять в начале - если существует файл с обработанными данными, то открывать его, пропуская предварительную обработку, а в противном случае обработать и сохранить обработанные данные. Таким образом данные будут обработаны только один раз.

Пример:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

fn = r"/path/to/data.csv"
fn_stage1 = r"/path/to/data_stage1.parquet"

if os.path.exist(fn_stage1):
    df = pd.read_parquet(fn_stage1)
else:
    df = pd.read_csv(fn)
    # process data here...
    df.to_parquet(fn_stage1)
```

Comment: MaxU, спасибо за пример с кодом. Я об этом как-то не подумал даже. Это ведь действительно может упростить обработку. Спасибо!

Comment: @ЕвгенийТолюпа, всегда пожалуйста)